# In PL/SQL finding execution timing of procedure and function

Tags: oracle, plsql, timing

In PL/SQL I have one package in which multiple procedures, functions, and cursors are used
now how I will find each procedure and function execution timing from the package...

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it manually; here's how:

I created a "log" table:

```
CREATE TABLE sd_log
(
   id             NUMBER,
   datum          DATE,
   program        VARCHAR2 (60),
   position       NUMBER,
   description    VARCHAR2 (200)
);
```

There's an autonomous transaction log procedure:

```
   PROCEDURE p_log (par_program      IN VARCHAR2,
                    par_position     IN NUMBER,
                    par_description  IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO sd_log (id,
                          datum,
                          program,
                          position,
                          description)
         SELECT seqlog.NEXTVAL,
                SYSDATE,
                par_program,
                par_position,
                par_description
           FROM DUAL;

      COMMIT;
   END p_log;
```

Procedures and functions (either standalone or packaged) look like this; as you can see, I'm not logging only the whole procedure, but each step within I'm interested in. It helps if you want to narrow down which piece of your code takes too much time so that you could optimize it.

```
   PROCEDURE p_cp2sm
   IS
      l_program   VARCHAR2 (60) := 'PKG_SD.P_CP2SM';
      l_position  NUMBER;
   BEGIN
      l_position := 0;
      p_log (l_program, l_position, 'Start');

      p_set_oldkey;

      l_position := 1;
      p_log (l_program, l_position, 'Truncate partition');

      pkg_mig.p_trunc_subpar (
            'alter table xxx truncate partition ' || g_par);

      l_position := 2;
      p_log (l_program, l_position, 'Insert');

      INSERT INTO sd_ap (...)
         SELECT ...
           FROM ...;

      l_position := 2.5;
      p_log (l_program, l_position, 'Inserted: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);

      l_position := 3;
      p_log (l_program, l_position, 'End');
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         l_position := NULL;
         p_log (l_program, l_position, SQLERRM);
         RAISE;
   END p_cp2sm;
```

Finally, if you want to trace execution and see how long each step took, run

```
     SELECT id,
       program,
       position,
       datum,
       LEAD (datum) OVER (ORDER BY id) datum_next,
       (LEAD (datum) OVER (ORDER BY id) - datum) * 24 * 60 * 60 diff_seconds,
       description
     FROM sd_log
     ORDER BY id;
```

Adjust it to your needs, if you want.